# Transition with walk cycle

Tags: nla-editor

I made a walk cycle action : the character has nothing in his hands.
Then, I made an action to take an object.
Then, I would like my character to keep his path, using walk cycle action again, and with the object in his hands.

The problem is that the walk cycle action does not work when there is the object in the hands.
More precisely, I think it is because I made a mistake while doing the transition between the action to take the object, and the action to start again the walk cycle action.

How do you do such thing properly?

Answer (score 1):

We have to guess, as you did not provide us with a minimal example file that demonstrates your issue. Most likely, the "object in hands" action contains fcurves for the rest of the body too, not just the arm/hand holding the object. These then override the walk cycle. If my guess is correct, the solution lies in removing the lower body fcurves from the "object in hands" action.

Comment: Yes thank you that was exactly what I was thinking: my "object in hands" action seems to override my walk cycle.

Comment: In fact, yes, the "object in hands" action contains fcurves for the lower body. But at the end of this action, I tried to make the bottom as definied for the walk cycle. And I thought that way it would work. But it is not the case. So I need to make a 2nd walk cycle action?

Comment: I need to add that I dont want to have both actions ("hold objects" and walk cycle) working at the same time. I juste want to play walk cycle action just after having taken the object.

Comment: Like Sybren said, try getting a dropbox account and then post the link to a .blend here.  That said, if you just want the character to walk, then pick up the object, put your walk strip wherever, make sure it's extrapolation is set to 'Hold Forward', and at the end of the walk strip, add the pick up strip and make sure the curves for the lower body are deleted.

Comment: alternative to dropbox: post .blend here http://www.pasteall.org/blend/ and send us that link.